# Makefile does not recognize target definition

Tags: makefile

I'm working on a project with the Dialogic DivaSDK to be able to analyze telephone calls. Since the DivaSDK supports Java via JNI, I wanted to give the samples a try. Unfortunately: the whole Java documentation is not as complete as the C# one is. So it seems to be like fishing in murky waters.
In my first step I wanted to look into the sample ( [Link to DivaSDK with Sample Files](http://downloads.eicon.com/p/dsapi/linux/11/112-710/download.htm)  )files and try them out. Each sample has a makefile which has to be run. The only part within the manual which scratches my problem sounds like this:

> For details how to compile and link your application please have a look at any of the samples provided with the Diva SDK. In every sample subdirectory you will find a makefile, that describes the compilation and link process of that application. The evaluation of the makefile requires some knowledge of shell scripting and makefile syntax and is beyond the scope of this document.

My problem right now is that the given makefile doesn't work the way it is supposed to be. I get the **error "No Targets"** Since I have not that much knowledge of makefiles, I can't figure out what is wrong with that file.

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#  makefile to geenrate the Diva SDK Java sample "SimpleApp".  This makefile 
#  generate the class files for teh framework and the sample and creates 
#  a SimpleApp.jar that can be executed via jav -jar SimpleApp
#  
#  The makefile assumes that the java development enmvironment is installed and 
#  the java tools are accessable from the command prompt.
#
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

FRAMEWORK_PATH=..\..\Framework
FRAMEWORK=$(FRAMEWORK_PATH)\DivaAPI.java $(FRAMEWORK_PATH)\DivaCallBase.java

BIN_DIR=.\bin
SRC_DIR=.\src

TRAGET=SimpleApp

#edited with hint from @Aaron Digulla
all : $(BIN_DIR)\$(TRAGET).jar

SRC=$(SRC_DIR)\SimpleApp.java \
    $(SRC_DIR)\AppCall.java


$(BIN_DIR)\$(TRAGET).jar: $(SRC)
@echo #-----------------------------------------------
@echo # Generate class files
@echo #-----------------------------------------------
javac -d $(BIN_DIR) -sourcepath $(FRAMEWORK_PATH) $(FRAMEWORK) $(SRC)
@echo #-----------------------------------------------
@echo # Generate jar files and clean class and manifest
@echo #-----------------------------------------------
copy $(SRC_DIR)\manifest.txt $(BIN_DIR)
cd $(BIN_DIR)
jar -cvfm $(TRAGET).jar manifest.txt *.class > nul
del *.class
del manifest.txt
cd ..
@echo #-----------------------------------------------
@echo # $(BIN_DIR)\$(TARGET).jar successfully created
@echo #-----------------------------------------------
```

It seems, that the target definition is wrong, but I don't know in which way. Any tips would be very much appreciated.

**edit1:** With the hint from @Aaron Digulla it works a little bit better. At least the target is recognized. But now there is an error which tells me, that there are no rules to create the jar.

**edit2:** Well... It seems that the filepaths are wrong. If I replace some of the backslashes ( "\" ) with normal slashes ( "/" ), the compiling starts. It stops at copy though...

Comment: On most versions of `make` I've dealt with, the commands (but not the `target : dependencies` bit) for each target *must* be indented, usually with a single <tab>. Don't know if that's your problem, but depending on how picky your version of `make` is, it's probably at least not helping...

Comment: Thank you for your response. You're right there is an indent needed, but I couldn't figure out how to set them in the WYSIWYG Editor. In my file they are present.

Comment: Note that (in most make implementations) the indent _must_ be a tab; multiple spaces won't do.  Also, at least on unix makes, each line is a separate process, so doing `cd` in one line won't change the directory on the next (try `cd $(BIN_DIR); jar -cvfm ...`)

Comment: The lines after the `.jar:` target must be indented by one tab in order to be recognized as commands.

Answer (score 2):

The error means there is no target `all` in the Makefile and `make` cowardly refuses to continue.

My guess is that this Makefile is supposed to be called from another Makefile.

Add this line to the Makefile:

```
all : $(BIN_DIR)\$(TRAGET).jar
```

and it should work. If the error persist, make sure you use GNU make or try `make all`

Comment: You guessed right, the makefile can be called from another one. But that doesn't work either (with a lot of different errors). 
With your code Makefile can at least take the next step. But now Makefile tells me that there are no rules to create the jar.

Comment: Is that on windows or linux?

Comment: The Makefile was written for Windows. Replace `\` with `/`, `copy` -> `cp`, `del` -> `rm`

Comment: @RobertSchröder which version of make? pmake?  bmake? GNU make?